# Seven-segment display pinout

Tags: pic, proteus, 7segmentdisplay, pinout

Im working on a project with a 4-digit 7-segment display. The display is a FQY3042BUR-21 0916.

I designed the circuit in Proteus and there were 8 data pins (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,dp) and 4 digit select pins(1,2,3,4). But the real thing has 6 pins on each side (12 in total). How can I know which pins are which? (I read the datasheet but couldn't understand. I'm really new to this.)

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to include datasheet links for the devices in question. The information is probably in there and someone will help explain it.

Comment: If you have a multimeter with a diode-drop function you can find combinations that illuminate particular segments and work it out from there

Comment: The OP does not identify the controller or LED module. A typical 12-pin module looks like this [image](https://www.luckylight.cn/media/component/images/KW4-361AVA.jpg) see data sheet [here](https://www.luckylight.cn/media/component/data-sheet/KW4-361AVA.pdf)